# Script to simulate Guest Mode

Tags: powershell, windows-7, batch-file

This is my first question here so, sorry if I break any rule I didn't know yet or don't follow any good practice. But, let's go.

I have a Windows 7 laptop and, usually, colleagues ask me to use it to google something, use Word or something else. I'd like to have a secure area for guests (like what Guest Mode was going to be, until it was removed from Windows 7 final version), enabling guests to browse, do what they want and, during the logoff, undo any changes made and wipe guest user data. As I'm former linux user, my first thought was something like a script called by Cron or on the Init appropriate level.

After googling a bit, I've found information about logon and logoff scripts. I know nearly nothing about scripting in MS platform. Do you think that this approach would be a good solution to my problem? If it is, in which language would I have to write this script? If possible, please provide some simple examples. After getting the basic concepts I can handle the rest.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hoping this can answer your question, even though it will not include batch scripting.

Here is a guest account on windows 7:
[image: Proof of guest account]
<sub>(source: [sevenforums.com](https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/8417d1240117767-guest-account-turn-off-log_on.jpg))</sub>

1. Open the Control Panel (All Items View).
2. Click on the User Accounts icon.
3. Click on the Manage another account link. (See screenshot below)

[image: Manage another user]
<sub>(source: [sevenforums.com](https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/8418d1240117767t-guest-account-turn-off-step1.jpg))</sub>

4. If prompted by UAC, then click on Yes.
5. Click on the listed Guest account. (See screenshot below)

[image: Click guest account]
<sub>(source: [sevenforums.com](https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/8419d1240117767t-guest-account-turn-off-step2.jpg))</sub>

6. Click on the Turn On button. (See screenshot below)

[image: Turn on guest account]
<sub>(source: [sevenforums.com](https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/8420d1240117767t-guest-account-turn-off-step3.jpg))</sub>

7. The guest account is now turned on. Close the User Accounts window. (See screenshot below)

[image: Congrats!]
<sub>(source: [sevenforums.com](https://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/8421d1240117767t-guest-account-turn-off-step4.jpg))</sub>

A script to delete things is:

```
rd c:\directory1\ /s /q
md c:\directory1
rd c:\directory2\ /s /q
md c:\directory2
```

ect.

so...

```
rd "Insert filepath you want removed here" /s /q
md "Same filepath"
```

For each directory your want removed, you must have a rd and md.

Save this into your "startup" folder so it will run each time you log-in.

Comment: I did this, actually. The problem is that after the logoff, any data saved in the Guest user Documents folder is kept to the next login, and I wanted to erase this data on the logoff, so I could always keep a clean environment to every user that logs in.

Comment: I shall write a script to delete these folders upon logout. please list all filepaths you wsant cleared at loggout.

Comment: Well, let's say that it's C:\Users\<username>\Documents and C:\Users\<username>\Downloads, for example.

Comment: Hey man, no problem! If you need any more help, feel free to recomment and I can help you out (please note that this script will run at login of any user.)